# How to add new table in tablecell in asp.net

Tags: asp.net, cells

How to add a new table in tablecell... .

```
Table tblTasks = new Table();

TableRow tr = new TableRow();


tr.Cells.Add(new Table());
```

something like that

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Create `TableCell` with your Table and add that cell like below

```
var cell =new TableCell();
cell.Controls.Add(new Table());
tr.Cells.Add(cell);
```